# Add new tags [ada-language] [gnat-compiler] [cobol-language] [gnucobol-compiler]

Tags: discussion

While creating my [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50368/raspberry-pi-and-ada-compiler-gnat-on-raspbian-gpio) I found that there are no tags for the ADA language, the GNAT compiler, nor the COBOL language and the GNUCOBOL compiler.

ADA is used in many real-time critical infrastructure systems in the industry (aviation, energy, railways, military, ...) and COBOL is still the #1 language in the financial and administrative world, according to different sources.

Wouldn't it be interesting to add some new tags like 
 - ada-language
 - gnat-compiler or ada-compiler
 - cobol-language
 - gnucobol-compiler or cobol-compiler
or something alike ?

Kind regards,

J.M.

Comment: Do people still use Ada?  I rather thought it had died.  I'm not sure what the policy is on creating fresh tags.  I don't think Ada/GNAT/COBOL will be used much.

Comment: http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada

Comment: I was being cheeky.  I've only used when it was mandated on military projects.

Comment: ADA is a modern ISO/IEC 2012 certified language
Cfr. http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=61507
At his time there a different job positions open in Brussels (aviation control systems)

Comment: Ada not ADA.  I've only used the (original) Ada 83 and Ada 95 variants.

Comment: I'm currently using the gnat compiler (2016) with the Ada 2012 standard on RPi Raspbian and on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
(taking into account your remark on upper/lower case - LOL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this page from the help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), new tags are added when people compose questions, try to add a tag they think would be appropriate, and it turns out not to exist -- in which case the tag is created and henceforth available.

However, as also noted there, this requires 300 rep.

So, if you notice there's no `ada` tag, it's for one of these reasons:

1. No one has asked any questions here they think worth applying this to.
2. Someone asked a question they thought it would be applicable to, but could not create the tag because of the rep bar.
3. As per #2, but instead of lacking the necessary 300 rep, the user was unaware of the mechanism.

Searching for "ada" here is problematic because of Adafruit, one of the better known online Pi retailers, and a significant information/tutorial hub.  However, searching for "cobol" only turns up 2 questions, this one and [your related question from the main site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50368/5538), which means the explanation for that one is clearly #1.

Anyway, I've created an [ada](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ada) tag with [gnat](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnat) as a synonym and added it to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Generally we do not create tags in hopes that they may be used. If the tag does not exist it likely is the case that no one has needed it yet. I do not recall any questions about Ada or Cobol. Since you do not have enough rep to create a tag, and you have a question you feel needs the tag you can add a comment mentioning one of the Mods and we can create the tag.

Second meta is the proper place for this type of question. The main site is intended for questions about the Pi, and meta is for questions about the site and its usage.

I suggest that you read through the site's [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) sections.

Comment: AFAIK (could be wrong...nagging feeling I realized I was about this recently and have forgotten) it is *impossible* to create a tag without actually using it.   That being the case, you could see it as a flaw or a feature but it is presumably intended to be the latter -- which makes sense, it would not help for various busy bodies to clutter the tags section with things they *think* people might want at some point in the future.

Comment: I found the suggestion on the site to post a request for a new tag via meta, so that - if enough support for the idea - someone with enough rep can add it
I found out that searching for ADA gave many 'false positives', eg. many about Lady Ada and Adafruit (which I both like very much), but not about the ADA language.
I'm currently rediscovering COBOL and ADA in a high security real-time environment in which we are looking to integrate Raspberry Pi's
Also see https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~dirk.craeynest/ada-belgium/
I will certainly use the tags, if accepted, to post about my work.

Comment: @jmlietaer You mention posting about your work, keep in mind this is a Q&A site not a forum. Also posting a question will come before the tag as goldilocks mentioned.

Comment: I generalized my request for new tags to 'compiler' and 'language' to create a structured way of retrieving information about languages like C, C++, C#, ... since compiler related Q&A and language related Q&A are very different and the language names are quite sensitive to result in 'false positives'.
Just a suggestion to improve the tagging system logic.

Comment: @Steve Robillard: With 'posting about my work' I mean replying on questions about the use of ADA/COBOL on Raspberry Pi (based on the experience I build up during my work) or asking questions about the subject (with the appropriate tag when it is accepted), as I did on my first question on which joan (cfr. supra) replied with a very useful suggestion.

Comment: @jmlietaer When making this type of suggestion you should have some solid example questions to illustrate your point. Second, a language tag is no improvement because how does your suggested usage disambiguate machine language, natural language, keyboard language settings etc. Lastly, you have in the last couple of hours changed your mind and usage of tags - should we continually update the tags as your  understanding evolves as well?

Comment: Just to reinforce the point: *There are no tags without questions.*  So no one has the rep or power to create a new `cobol` tag unless it is in the context of asking (or editing) a question involving COBOL.

Comment: I was referring to the answer in  [this link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260631/i-cant-add-a-tag-because-i-have-less-than-1500-reputation-points) where a moderator suggested the procedure to propose the tag to the community.

Comment: @Steve Robillard: By mentioning 'or something alike' in my initial question I respect the right of the community to use the best-suited solution to add the -compiler and -language tags to have the best results. This has nothing to do with changing my mind, but everything with suggesting the best solution chosen by those who know best the stackexchange way of doing things.
To reply to your questions about disambiguation: what about assembler-language and perhaps synonyms like asm-language or masm-language?
I did not ask for that since I have no questions about these subjects.

Comment: There's two things about that: 1) Consistency; we certainly aren't alone amongst S.E. sites that touch on programming in just using, e.g., `c++`.  If someone at some point manages to ask a question about big constrictors that is also rpi appropriate, then we can use a qualified `python-snake` tag (and hope this doesn't clash with a module name, lol).  2) On Stack Overflow, which is much larger and more programming centric, you will find compiler specific tags -- `icc`, `gcc`, `clang`, etc. -- but not `c-compiler` vs. `c-language`...

Comment: ... (the former is too pointless and abstract; note there are things such as `compiler-design` which could be combined with the `c` tag).  We could have the same thing when/where necessary (and in fact do, there's a `gcc` and a `clang`).   In the ada/gnat case, I think the very small volume makes them better off as synonyms instead of separate tags (but that could be revisited at any point, if suddenly we are flooded with questions indicating a need for differentiation).